# Corner symbol directly over a letter

Tags: math-mode, formatting

I'd like to know how to add a corner symbol directly above a letter in math-mode, such as in the following image:

[image: Corner over lambda]

I have tried the commands `\urcorner` or `\ulcorner` from the `amssymb` package and they are not what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,amssymb}
\newcommand\URcorneraccent{\rule[\dimexpr1.7pt-.5pt]{1ex}{.5pt}\rule{.5pt}{1.7pt}}
\newcommand\URcorner[1]{\ensurestackMath{\stackon[.8pt]{#1}{\URcorneraccent}}}
\begin{document}
\[
\mathfrak{L}(x) =\partial^\mu \URcorner\lambda(x)...\URcorner x
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If it is need in the smaller math styles, please let me know.